# Incrementing the significand of a floating-point number

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm searching with brute force for a floating point number with certain properties (small roundoff error of sin(a)^2+cos(a)^2-1). I therefore want to loop over the neighborhood of a given floating point number by incrementing the significand.

Is there a simple way to do that in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C99 has nextafter and nexttoward; they weren't present in C90.

Comment: That's the answer I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you find yourself on a backwards platform that lacks `nextafter( )`, you can always use a union (subject to some caution about compilers making strong aliasing assumptions):

```
union { double d; int64_t i; } number;
number.d = initialValue;
doSomethingWithTheDouble(number.d);
number.i++; // increment to next double value away from zero
```

because of the way floating-point numbers are encoded, this works even when crossing binade boundaries; just be aware that it doesn't do the "right thing" when it crosses zero.